# react native app crash after sending notification from firebase via gcm

Tags: android, react-native, google-cloud-messaging

whenever i try to send notification from firebase my app crash.

then i am trying to figure it out where the crash come from with adb logcat.

it seems like there is something wrong with gcm dependencies, i have no idea where the erorr come from.

it said "unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"

here is the error picture :
[image: app crashed]

my build.gradle dependecies :

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml look like this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.hidroponik">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.hidroponik.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.hidroponik.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      

      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                    android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@android:color/white"/><!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.hidroponik" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > --><receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/><!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerServiceGcm"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- </ Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > --><!-- < Else > -->
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

i am sorry for the long code please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok i figured it out.

first of all it was my bad that i don't add the

```
"com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
```

dependencies at build gradle.

and then i found another problem after this.

the problem is that gcm is deprecated.

> On April 10, 2018, Google deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client
> APIs were removed on May 29, 2019, and currently any calls to those
> APIs can be expected to fail. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud
> Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM
> infrastructure, plus many new features.

and then i follow the migration guide at ==> [GCM Migrate to FCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)

in the guide is written that i should replace the build.gradle

this line

```
"com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
```

to

```
"com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4"
```

and then move to the AndroidManifest.xml i need to delete a certain code.
because

> The FCM SDK automatically adds all required permissions as well as the
> required receiver funtionality.

so this is what i delete from my AndroidManifest.xml

this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.hidroponik.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.hidroponik.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and this

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
  android:exported="true"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
  <category android:name="com.hidroponik" />
```

after that the notifications work well without any error.

i hope this question can help others.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks

Comment: glad that this help you